# Opening *.svg with IE9 raises 'Open, Save As' dialog

Tags: internet-explorer-9, svg

I am attempting to open an SVG file with Internet Explorer 9 (32-bit). When doing so, I am prompted with the standard `Open, Save, Save As` dialog.

This happens when dropping an SVG file onto IE or opening it directly from Explorer. However, it displays properly when the full, local filepath is entered straight into the address bar.

[image: Open, Save, Save As dialog, 32-bit IE9]

A [similar question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/ieitprocurrentver/thread/e1c1fab4-d6ad-4233-9083-f1bdbe17344e) was recently asked on Technet. The (unsatisfactory) answer suggests it is add-on related. And indeed, `Internet Explorer (No Add-Ons)` and `Internet Explorer (64-bit)` behave as expected. But neither the [reset utility](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9646978) nor manually disabling *every single* add-on has helped the 32-bit version.

I appreciate any suggestions or insight into this.

Comment: I guess it's a security setting relating to opening local files, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: @Randolph, that was my initial assumption as well. Turns out some (old) SVG software had reassigned the CLSID for the `image/svg+xml` MIME type. Assigning the `Browse In Place` CLSID (mirroring `text/html`, etc) solves this. Details in my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by assigning the `Browse In Place` CLSID to the offending content type. This will not affect Explorer's "Open With" association. The following `*.reg` script will alter type `image/svg+xml`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\image/svg+xml]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

**Credit**: Cheeso's `application/json` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2492211/311207).