# How to enable the 'Save and Open' option in Internet Explorer

Tags: microsoft-excel, internet-explorer, csv, internet-explorer-11

I've recently upgraded to Internet Explorer 11 and when I try to download/open a `*.csv` file I get the following options in IE.  The `Save and Open` option is greyed out.

Is there a setting I can change to allow me to save and open these files?  Excel docs (xlsx) open immediately without any clicking.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/368024/opening-svg-with-ie9-raises-open-save-as-dialog) similar post but it wasn't the same question.

[image]

Comment: Check Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > scroll down to Security > "Do not save encrypted pages to disk". What's it set to? Also is this your personal computer where you control all settings, or is this a company/work computer?

Comment: The "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" is unchecked.  This is a work computer, the settings are mainly controlled by GPO, but I can easily request changes to be made and deployed.  (I can change settings and test on my PC too for most of the options)

Comment: Determine if it's a GPO getting you: If you create a local user account and then log in as that local user, does it behave as expected? Also, does this apply to ANY CSV you try to download, or just this specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the problem website to the Compatibility View List. This worked for me.

In IE click "Tools" -> "Compatibility Settings" and enter in the problem website address.

You can add websites to the Compatibility View List via group policy too. It should be noted that websites added via group policy do not show up in the Compatibility View List on the client browser (at least from what I can tell).

Computer or User Configuration-> Policies-> Administrative Templates-> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Compatibility View